# Recode multiple values inplace

Tags: r

I have a SPSS code for recoding variables that I'm trying to replicate in R.

The code is:

```
recode variable (1 = 7) (2 = 5) (3 = 4) (4 = 3) (5 = 1) (6 = 2).
```

How can I replicate this is R (better if it's a short piece of code).

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

```
vec <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
dplyr::recode(vec, 
       `1` = 7,
       `2` = 5,
       `3` = 4,
       `4` = 3,
       `5` = 1,
       `6` = 2)
```